# Command binding doesn't function if its inside an item template of a listbox

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

I have the following user control

```
<ListBox   ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" 
           SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}" 
           VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="166" >
            <ListBox.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <StackPanel >
                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                        <Button Content="Add" Background="Transparent" Command="{Binding NewItemCommand}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ListBox.Template>

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button  Height="16" Width="16" Background="Transparent" Command="{Binding DeleteItemCommand}">
                            <Image Source="images/delete-icon.png" />
                        </Button>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

and i have a view model for it with two commands, the first command that you can see above `NewItemCommand` is working fine, how ever the second command `DeleteItemCommand` doesn't function.

is it because its in the item template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is because the `DataContext` for the `ItemTemplate` is the Item from `Persons` not the `ViewModel`

To bind the `DeleteItemCommand` on each item you will need to bind back to the `ViewModel` that is holding the command

Example, binding to the `DataContext` of the `ListBox`

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.DeleteItemCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}" />
```

---

### Edit:

If you want to remove the item that the button was clicked on you can pass the item the button belongs to as the `CommandParameter` and handle that in your comman, Not sure what type of command you are using but this is simple if you are using `RelayCommand` or `DelegateCommand`

```
 <Button Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.DeleteItemCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}"
         CommandParameter="{Binding}" />

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DeleteItemCommand = new RelayCommand(person => DeletePerson(person as Person));
}

private void DeletePerson(Person person)
{
    Collection.Remove(person);
}
```

Comment: perfect thanks, any idea on how would you remove an item from the collection? my delete command deletes the selected item , however the item doesnt get the focused if i click its remove button without focusing it first

Comment: You could pass the `Item` as the `CommandParameter` and remove it from the collection