# How do you bind Commands to jump lists LongListSelector in MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-8, command

I have the following xaml which is bound to a command... but I have no idea how I can pass information to the command to know which item was tapped:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="OrganisationsItemTemplate">
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5,0,0,0">
                <Button ... Command = "{Binding LoadPage}">
                    <Grid Margin="0,0,5,0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="67"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Background="Transparent">
                            <Border Background="White" BorderThickness="0" Width="62" Height="62" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,5">
                                <Image Source="{Binding image.thumbnail_link}" Width="62" Height="62"></Image>
                            </Border>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,5" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
```

These items in the jump list will hopefully open a new xaml page up which will show details specific to the item I chose. for example if I select Coca Cola as the organisation, it should then show the Detail.xaml which will list details on the Coca Cola organisation (fetched by the organisation ID).

If you recommend me using a hyperlinkbutton instead, do you have an example, If I put one in, I get the following error:

```
+       ExceptionObject {System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.}  System.Exception {System.ArgumentException}
```

I assume that this is because I am nesting other elements within it... which, is kinda.. what I need to do?

Comment: Can you not just pass the information to the `Command` in the `CommandParameter`

Comment: what what what.. I didn't know that was there.. ooo.. ill search on bing thanks (lol, bing)

Comment: There is an example here on a similar question yesterday http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352992/command-binding-doesnt-function-if-its-inside-an-item-template-of-a-listbox/19353052#19353052

Comment: Thanks, much easier now I know what to search for ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass a CommandParameter to your Command and give it the relevant object.

```
<Button Command="{Binding LoadPage}" CommandParameter={Binding ElementName=ParentItem Path=DataContext}">
```

Comment: What does the ElementName refer to?

Comment: ElementName refers to any XAML node in the Visual Tree that has an x:Name. You should give the ItemsControl a name and pass it to ElementName and then reference SelectedItem for the Path most likely (I haven't tested it).